# Which design pattern to use in a project for books (adding/editing/deleting) books?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm making a .Net project, in c# and asp.net mvc. It is a web app for books.
The user which will log in will be able to see a list of the books, to edit the information about the books (title, image, genre, description, etc.), and to delete and to add books.

I'm a beginner in design patterns and I have no idea if in my case it would be smart or even possible to use a design pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a principle above the usage of *Design Patterns*:

> **KISS**
>
> *Keep it simple stupid*.

In your requirements (to simply edit and show a list of domain objects with no behavior etc.) the need of a *Design Pattern* is not recommended.

As requirements rise you could refactor the current code base to use design patterns.

But by the use of a web technology you will always use the Model-View-Controller (or Model-View-Presenter-Controller or anything in this direction). This pattern then will use Observer to update changes.

Note: There are several types of design patterns. From architectural (eg. 3-tier web app), to implementation (Observer), to idioms (for loop).

Comment: Agreed, there is no simple way to get design patterns, they have to be learn in principle and them applied in practice with experience.